# Do printf(1) implementations differ in how they handle argument overflow?

Tags: printf

Every instance I've found of `printf(1)` (that is, the command-line version; as opposed to `printf(3)`, the C library) **repeats** its format-string to consume more when presented with too many arguments, allowing for constructions such as

```bsh
printf '%s\n' "${headers[@]}" "" "${body}" > http_client_socket
```

However, is this platform-specific? If so, which platforms does it *differ from this* on?

Additionally (and regardless of the answer to the previous question), is it in the spec, or is it an undefined behavior?

Comment: It's in the POSIX spec, see quote and link in the accepted answer ^there

Comment: @muru Aha, nice! So it is POSIX-specified. (I'm still a bit curious if any major implementations buck this, but this answers the core of my curiosity.)

Comment: You could edit the question to focus only on that and have it reopened. I can't say for sure, but the manpages of most of the older systems in https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi have some variant of the phrase "The format string is reused as often as necessary to satisfy the arguments" (where printf is provided by the system in the first place). The exception was [HP UX](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=printf&sektion=1&manpath=HP-UX+11.22), which still says it conforms to the POSIX spec, so I assume the manpage simply didn't mention this detail.